# How to prevent OAuth2 client from doing 2nd /oauth2/authorize redirect to OAuth2 server? First works, second throws [authorization_request_not_found]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

OAuth2 Code Grant Flow is working, but it triggers a second redirect to the Authz server which leads to an exception. What can I do to fix this? Or debug it further?

I am not sure if this is a misconfiguration on my part, or maybe a weird side effect because I am running the OAuth2 Client and OAuth2 Authorization Server in a single Spring Boot application (for development).
I think the OAuth2 Client and OAuth2 Authorization Server are normally separate Spring Boot applications, but I have both in a single application for development at this time.

Configuration

- SecurityFilterChain: https://github.com/justincranford/spring/blob/main/src/main/java/com/github/justincranford/spring/config/SecurityFilterChainConfig.java#L122-L181
- OAuth2 Client Config: https://github.com/justincranford/spring/blob/main/src/main/resources/application.properties#L223-L241
- OAuth2 Authz Server RegisteredClientRepository: https://github.com/justincranford/spring/blob/main/src/main/java/com/github/justincranford/spring/config/SecurityFilterChainConfig.java#L307-L334
- OAuth2 Authz Server AuthorizationServerSettings: https://github.com/justincranford/spring/blob/main/src/main/java/com/github/justincranford/spring/config/SecurityFilterChainConfig.java#L340-L352

From the browser, it appears OAuth2 Code Grant Flow fails:

1. Start the Spring Boot application `com.github.justincranford.spring.Application`
2. Open `https://127.0.0.1:8443/` in a browser
3. Click `Internal OAuth2 Client` button on main page to initiate flow, which shows /login page
4. Submit Username `appuser` and Password `appuser`
5. UI displays `[authorization_request_not_found]`

However, from the logs, OAuth2 Code Grant Flow actually triggers twice. First time works, because I see these tokens returned from authz server to client:

1. access_token: eyJraWQiOiIxIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJhcHB1c2VyIiwiYXVkIjoiaW50ZXJuYWwtb2F1dGgyLWxvZ2luIiwibmJmIjoxNjgxMDY5MTc3LCJzY29wZSI6WyJvcGVuaWQiLCJwcm9maWxlIiwibWVzc2FnZS5yZWFkIiwibWVzc2FnZS53cml0ZSJdLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo4NDQzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjgxNjczOTc3LCJpYXQiOjE2ODEwNjkxNzd9.kbmjVquLRg6Y459k2aWH1VI6XmDA8fUyk6ETngYAwCZAwF2fK9tIa4GoAhOKnssSP-7d-0RniXegFp2SkVKQ-WJkwzbDZQUBbGkdFX3LFthtOdmDrLGg_uWLIaZWs-aEgxDwFWr1cDj4RFMaGuPg0gTadt4nbJYbuv_02m44FXVZAeD8gfdsIhk2jl7FsduVlz6QHqEdfQEtzRw4Uyo6rhjJQbvCFl1qn-wUZb2EUbXsceoMpQhWMrHVjgdpaRZdBiLpS2TR4byeU9JKFNLtPALxHOZ4yn4Vsh3U4VxxdOD7RGDMqmbKelU2tQcIN8gKe3pRaFxbbYe-myZQH99gbA
2. refresh_token: I8CImVTygAaTLBQ8mrUVZ7hQT5qufW1IC7eLp2l4xnieTlDB5leH9qg9PW4jSYGJbuyyS72km-Z_zrzOfrP2APSMhZ7LFriQ2njG4zakpZfszjnlfqj9FMLDZ3TMSGnE
3. id_token: eyJraWQiOiIxIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJhcHB1c2VyIiwiYXVkIjoiaW50ZXJuYWwtb2F1dGgyLWxvZ2luIiwiYXpwIjoiaW50ZXJuYWwtb2F1dGgyLWxvZ2luIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODQ0MyIsImV4cCI6MTY4MTA3MDk3NywiaWF0IjoxNjgxMDY5MTc3LCJub25jZSI6ImRFTC1JUmxtRENsUjk4ME5pZkhCN1pFdnoyVlpIb2pCY0gxeGZENklaUFUifQ.Tr8YJQ7Rkdef3Xt6ERs1hF4VgBgHa_cR_9BdG0nHE23jN0M3SW-go-qtGAYaHw_-ALPqn-dLeglQcedBYsLj9du-7v728yERQ_PD05zKCK_B8UA5P4b0vnzvGNq0TLFJp8O06JIa0XJ9akVv6KCHtOkH07wInwKLJlozIlkwY0sjiJYwHaGSnim6t6fwS2LjNOAiEBzwOHJ65ZTveQENhA5OLybhE-wU1Aj_bG1nfpMeB-KGCboVi4kpa_AcirUzma35Wv1guKZpADuGWdmoN1uB87Hzvc3_A0t6_KKeC3GSLhlcyy1gyIqEe6JX_Q3lIjvKD-HK76XFI4N02u9lcA

I also see these events after the above tokens are logged:

1. AuthenticationSuccessEvent
2. HttpSessionIdChangedEvent
3. SessionFixationProtectionEvent
4. InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent

However, right after the above events are logged, the client does an unexpected redirect back to the OAuth2 Authorization Server. There are no TRACE logs to indicate why that happens, and I tried debugging it but I don't understand the internals enough to diagnose it. What eventually happens during the second flow is an exception, and that is what the end-user sees in the browser.

Here is a snippet from the log where the flow ends successful, but then the client triggers a unexpected 2nd flow.

```
2023-04-09T15:39:37.459-04:00 TRACE 9992 --- [0.1-8443-exec-3] AllApplicationEventsListener             : AuthenticationSuccessEvent [source=OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [appuser], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_message.read, SCOPE_message.write, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{sub=appuser, aud=[internal-oauth2-login], azp=internal-oauth2-login, iss=https://127.0.0.1:8443, exp=2023-04-09T20:09:37Z, iat=2023-04-09T19:39:37Z, nonce=dEL-IRlmDClR980NifHB7ZEvz2VZHojBcH1xfD6IZPU}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=5E04679E64DE374482CD26A3C5B7E8C7], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_message.read, SCOPE_message.write, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2023-04-09T15:39:37.460-04:00 TRACE 9992 --- [0.1-8443-exec-3] AllApplicationEventsListener             : HttpSessionIdChangedEvent [source=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@33673d6c]
2023-04-09T15:39:37.460-04:00 DEBUG 9992 --- [0.1-8443-exec-3] .s.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy : Changed session id from 5E04679E64DE374482CD26A3C5B7E8C7
2023-04-09T15:39:37.460-04:00 TRACE 9992 --- [0.1-8443-exec-3] AllApplicationEventsListener             : SessionFixationProtectionEvent [source=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [appuser], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_message.read, SCOPE_message.write, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{sub=appuser, aud=[internal-oauth2-login], azp=internal-oauth2-login, iss=https://127.0.0.1:8443, exp=2023-04-09T20:09:37Z, iat=2023-04-09T19:39:37Z, nonce=dEL-IRlmDClR980NifHB7ZEvz2VZHojBcH1xfD6IZPU}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=5E04679E64DE374482CD26A3C5B7E8C7], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_message.read, SCOPE_message.write, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2023-04-09T15:39:37.460-04:00 DEBUG 9992 --- [0.1-8443-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [appuser], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_message.read, SCOPE_message.write, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{sub=appuser, aud=[internal-oauth2-login], azp=internal-oauth2-login, iss=https://127.0.0.1:8443, exp=2023-04-09T20:09:37Z, iat=2023-04-09T19:39:37Z, nonce=dEL-IRlmDClR980NifHB7ZEvz2VZHojBcH1xfD6IZPU}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=5E04679E64DE374482CD26A3C5B7E8C7], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_message.read, SCOPE_message.write, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@33673d6c]
2023-04-09T15:39:37.461-04:00 DEBUG 9992 --- [0.1-8443-exec-3] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [appuser], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_message.read, SCOPE_message.write, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{sub=appuser, aud=[internal-oauth2-login], azp=internal-oauth2-login, iss=https://127.0.0.1:8443, exp=2023-04-09T20:09:37Z, iat=2023-04-09T19:39:37Z, nonce=dEL-IRlmDClR980NifHB7ZEvz2VZHojBcH1xfD6IZPU}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=5E04679E64DE374482CD26A3C5B7E8C7], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_message.read, SCOPE_message.write, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]
2023-04-09T15:39:37.461-04:00 TRACE 9992 --- [0.1-8443-exec-3] AllApplicationEventsListener             : InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent [source=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [appuser], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_message.read, SCOPE_message.write, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{sub=appuser, aud=[internal-oauth2-login], azp=internal-oauth2-login, iss=https://127.0.0.1:8443, exp=2023-04-09T20:09:37Z, iat=2023-04-09T19:39:37Z, nonce=dEL-IRlmDClR980NifHB7ZEvz2VZHojBcH1xfD6IZPU}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=5E04679E64DE374482CD26A3C5B7E8C7], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_message.read, SCOPE_message.write, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2023-04-09T15:39:37.461-04:00 DEBUG 9992 --- [0.1-8443-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to https://127.0.0.1:8443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=internal-oauth2-login&scope=openid%20profile%20message.read%20message.write&state=vO2wmwN1_5Nf-1jKNo4m4LTe2W5atlQJSG4k5tf63x8%3D&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1:8443/login/oauth2/code/internal-oauth2-login&nonce=dEL-IRlmDClR980NifHB7ZEvz2VZHojBcH1xfD6IZPU&continue
...
2023-04-09T15:39:37.478-04:00 TRACE 9992 --- [0.1-8443-exec-6] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Failed to process authentication request

org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [authorization_request_not_found] 
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
```

Full logs from my Spring Boot application from startup through to Code Flow success plus unexpected 2nd redirect:

- https://gist.github.com/justincranford/93eabb050a1ab707bb729af92f8554cc

I tried TRACE logging and debugging.

Comment: What stands out to me is that you are using a single filter chain to describe both the authorization server endpoints and the client endpoints. This is like saying that the authz server requires OAuth 2.0 login to get logged in (which it doesn't, it only requires form login). This might work, but that's where I would start looking. Have a filter chain for your app endpoints and another for your authz server endpoints. Also, if you are going to support form login as well as oauth, but they are all the same server, I guess I'm not seeing the point of having oauth at all, just use form login.